# Create a binary image of an object inside a Glass BDSF object

Tags: rendering, glass

For my PhD, I want to simulate objects (insects) inside amber pieces, then I would like to render the binary image of the object (i.e a segmentation of the object in the rendering view).

I managed to do something using an emission meterial for the object and then segment my final rendering using colors, but I would like to know if it is possible to dirrectly compute the binary mask (by for example getting informations from the ray tracing : knowing if a ray went through my object).

This is 2 rendering of my scene (I'm really interested into the deformation due to the fact that my "spider" is inside a refractive medium)

- Im 1 : Image without the amber
- Im 2 : Image with the amber
- Im 3 : Using an emission material to segment the color
- Im 4 : The binary mask taht I got, and that I would like to get directly from Blender (if it's possible).

You could ask, why not just using the color segmentation, well, I will have to simulate a lot of images, with different colors of amber, differents lightning, so, the emission color will be different at each time. It's still possible to create an adaptive algorithm for the segmentation but it would be way easier to get the mask directly.

So, if you have any idea of how to solve this, it would be perfect !

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.